# In MS-Excel: i want to extract the perticular string among the string

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have column string like that

```
"SD nbdhjhnbjhd"href="http://click.linksynergy.com/fs-bin/click?id=jj9Ho/gjL0I&offerid=228389.10000091&type=3&subid=0"dgfxhfh"hnfcnfdeer>
```

I want to exract the string that

```
http://click.linksynergy.com/fs-bin/click?id=jj9Ho/gjL0I&offerid=228389.10000091&type=3&subid=0
```

And store it same column.

Comment: Does it always start with `<a href="`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the string always starts with `<a href="`, you can use a `MID` and a `FIND`:

```
=MID(A2,10,FIND("""",A2,11)-10)
```

Assuming that the string is in cell A2.

I'm using `10` because `<a href="` is 9 characters long and the first relevant part is the 10th character.

EDIT: As per comment, you can try this instead:

```
=MID(A2,FIND("http",A2),FIND("subid=0",A2)-FIND("http",A2)+7)
```

For a second link to extract, try:

```
=MID(SUBSTITUTE(A2,B2,""),FIND("http",SUBSTITUTE(A2,B2,"")),FIND("subid=0",SUBS‌​TITUTE(A2,B2,""))-FIND("http",SUBSTITUTE(A2,B2,""))+7)
```

Comment: i want find the word start with "http" and end with "subid=0"

Comment: @chimbu How about the second formula?

Comment: if suppose string "subid=0" two times in A2  what can i do?

Comment: @chimbu Well, that'll be hard... :( you mean you need to extract all until the second `subid=0`? How would you make sure it's the right `subid=0`?

Comment: that second formula its extract first instance of "subid=0" in A2,this is want. if suppose in features i want to take instance of "subid=0". what'll i do?

Comment: @chimbu Can you give an example? The complexity of the formula will depend on how the data is.

Comment: <a href="http://click.linksynergy.com/fs-bin/click?id=jj9Ho/gjL0I&offerid=228389.10000091&type=3&subid=0" >Enjoy the sights, sounds and surf in Miami this summer.</a><IMG border=0 width=1 height=1 src="http://ad.linksynergy.com/fs-bin/show?id=jj9Ho/gjL0I&bids=228389.10000091&type=3&subid=0" >

Comment: @chimbu You might need to remove the first link first if you want to get both. For example, in C2, you could perhaps do: `=MID(SUBSTITUTE(A2,B2,""),FIND("http",SUBSTITUTE(A2,B2,"")),FIND("subid=0",SUBSTITUTE(A2,B2,""))-FIND("http",SUBSTITUTE(A2,B2,""))+7)` (I haven't tested it though)

Comment: @chimbu It's the newline in the comment which is inserting a foreign character in the excel. Let me put that formula as well in my answer (the formula is the same but it should be working). See the last formula.